# When creating a user in Django Admin it does not hash the password?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I am trying to Create a user from my Django Admin (the project is a rest API) using the Django REST framework.

admin.py

```
class UserFrame(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "email", "date_of_creation", "is_active"]
    list_editable = ["is_active"]
    
admin.site.register(models.AccountProfile, UserFrame)
```

The error I am getting:
**Unknown field (s) (date_joined, last_name, first_name) specified for AccountProfile**

AccountProfile is my custom user model which inherits from AbstractBaseUser and has a BaseUserManager.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you created a UserFrame model in a way that does not use your manager's create_user method.

If you create a custom user, you need to define a custom model form and model admin that handles the password properly. Unless passwords will not hashed when a user is created in the Django admin.

Check this out here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example
This example helps you to create a custom user.

Answer (score 0):

user.set_password(raw_password)

This is the method you need to include in your custom admin manager.
Let it know it has to hash those passwords.